# Why is exec('which ffmpeg') returning nothing in my application?

Tags: php, terminal, ffmpeg, exec

I'm trying to deal with FFMpeg for my application, but I'm encountering some difficulty in getting it set up. To instantiate or create an instance of FFMpeg, I need to call a `create()` method and pass through the operating locations of FFMpeg and FFProbe. To do this, I was hoping to be able to write:

```
        $ffmpeg = FFMpeg\FFMpeg::create([
                'ffmpeg.binaries' => exec('which ffmpeg'),
                'ffprobe.binaries' => exec('which ffprobe')
        ]);
```

But, sadly, the command `exec('which ffmpeg')` returns an empty string. If I run the 'which ffmpeg' command in Terminal, I get a response:

```
/usr/local/bin/ffmpeg
```

So why does it work in my terminal, but not when my PHP script tries to execute it?

I've tried a few solutions, such as appending `2>&1` to the end of the command, which did not help, running the command in `shell_exec()`, and placing the output in the second parameter of `exec()` which also did not solve my issue.

I feel like this may be some sort of weird permissions issue...

## Addendum

It has been brought to my attention that PHP cannot see my `$PATH` variable. From the console, `echo $PATH` produces:

```
/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.6.2/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:‌​/sbin:/opt/X11/bin:/usr/local/git/bin:/opt/ImageMagick/bin
```

While calling the same from my application with `exec()` produces:

```
/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin237.671000
```

Comment: does php have `read/execute` permissions on `/usr/local/bin/ffmpeg` ?

Comment: Unlikely. How can I find out?

Comment: `ls -al /usr/local/bin/ffmpeg` - you can set `read/execute` (rwxr-xr-x) permissions using: `chmod 755 /usr/local/bin/ffmpeg` , check this image: http://linuxcommand.org/images/permissions_diagram.gif

Comment: Your system search path is probably not available in PHP. Try `echo $PATH` on your console and in `exec()`.

Comment: @halfer `echo $PATH` in the console produces: `/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.6.2/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/opt/X11/bin:/usr/local/git/bin:/opt/ImageMagick/bin`, while `echo $PATH` in my app produces `/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin237.671000 `

Comment: @PedroLobito running your comment from my app produces `lrwxr-xr-x 1 Luke admin 33 Apr 28 22:18 /usr/local/bin/ffmpeg -> ../Cellar/ffmpeg/2.6.2/bin/ffmpeg237.671000 `. Attempting to `chmod` did not help, sadly.

Comment: The ffmpeg is located in "../Cellar/ffmpeg/2.6.2/bin/ffmpeg237.671000"

Comment: Okay, so it's located there, but how do I then get `which ffmpeg` to output this from my app?

Comment: Aha, re the `$PATH`, there's your answer. PHP cannot see your path `/usr/local/bin/`. Please add that information to your question, as it is very relevant (generally substantive updates belong in the question rather than comments anyway, here).

Comment: @halfer thanks, added! Now, how do I go about resolving this...

Comment: Well, one simple way is to set the path on a per-command basis, thus: `PATH=/usr/local/bin:$PATH php myscript.php`, which will supply the required search path plus its existing value. I'm not too much of an expert here - I guess the PHP version you've seen comes from `/etc/profile` whereas your console one comes from `$HOME/.bash_profile`? Not sure.

Comment: I will sometimes use `export` prior to a command to set up a new variable too, e.g. to add a new path for Travis, I do something like `export PATH=\`pwd\`/bin:$PATH` prior to running PHPUnit. Maybe playing around with that will help?